# Parse error in fstab - mounting a Windows share

Tags: 14.04, mount, fstab, cifs, sharing

I am having a problem editing /etc/fstab to mount a share on a Windows machine. I can manually mount the share using the command below without any problems:

```
sudo mount.cifs //machinename/sharename /media/sharedfolder -o user="My Username",password=MyPassword
```

But when I add this line to /etc/fstab I get a parse error:

```
//machinename/sharename  /media/sharedfolder cifs username="My Username", password=MyPassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the line in the fstab file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have whitespace between the comma-separated options, like

```
username="My Username", password=MyPassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
```

so change it to

```
username="My Username",password=MyPassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
```